# call() method cant be overriden

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I am learning RxJava in Android. I am following this tutorial [here](http://plavatvornica.com/rxjava-for-beginners/):

I coded the code posted below as stated in the tutoril. but I am not able to override the follwoing method

```
@Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {

        }
```

despite, it is mentioned in the tutorial that I have to use it. Android studio allows me to override only the follwoing method

```
@Override
        public void call(Object o) {

        }
```

but this method is not the one used in the tutorial.

please have let em know how to use the method used in the method

```
public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
```

as used in the tutorial

Also please have alook at gradle.build belwo, maybe I am using the wrong RxJava library

**code**

```
Observable myObservable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe() {

        @Override
        public void call(Object o) {

        }

        //this method cant be overriden
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {

        }
    });
```

**gradle.build**:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.10'
compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.16.1'
```

}

Comment: You probably want `Observable<String> myObservable`

Comment: And  write `new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() { ... }`. OnSubscribe's generic type defines the type of the parameter of `call`